# Structure and meaning of 'having a just a few' in the following paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

What is the structure and meaning of *'having a just a few'* in this paragraph?

> The major shift here is that we treat both entities and users groups as very cheap resources. Instead of having a just a few and structuring around them, we define what we want and then structure the groups around them. The burden them moves from complex code to maintaining the structure. I find this a very reasonable tradeoff for a simple security model and the flexibility that it gives me.

This paragraph is extracted from [a blog post.](http://ayende.com/blog/3109/rhino-security-overview-part-i)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd have to say that's a typographical error; the first "a" is out of place and the phrase doesn't make sense in that sentence (nor would it anywhere that I can think of). I think the author probably meant to say this (my emphasis on some of the phrases):

> The major shift here is that we treat both *Entities* and *Users Groups* as very cheap resources. Instead of having just a few [of them] and structuring around them, we define what we want ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guessed it the same as yours. But I am not sure.

Comment: @Liu You're welcome. I see several other typos in that article as well, so I definitely think this is just a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the phrase "just a few" doesn't clearly refer to anything.  Does it mean "just a few entities", or "just a few users groups", or "just a few resources", or something else entirely?  Given that the second sentence says "structure the groups around them", I'm inclined to think that the intended meaning is "just a few resources".  With that in mind, and not knowing any other context, I'd probably rewrite the paragraph as follows:

> If we treat both entities and users groups as very cheap resources, we
>   can then define the resources we want and structure our groups around
>   those resources.  The burden then moves from complex code to structure
>   maintenance. I find this a very reasonable tradeoff for a simple
>   security model and the flexibility that it gives me.

I hope this helps a little.

Comment: I think the problem is that the a typing mistake confused me, the ' a just a few'. Sorry for my poor English, and your analysis is wonderful.

Answer (score -1):

The major shift here is that we treat both entities and users groups as very cheap resources instead of having a just a few, and structuring around them, we define what we want and then structure the groups around them. The burden them moves from complex code to maintaining the structure. I find this a very reasonable tradeoff for a simple security model and the flexibility that it gives me.

Comment: @Liu I'm afraid I don't see how this would be helpful; it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: What on Earth is this answer supposed to be and why was it upvoted?

Comment: I am grateful to everyone who give attention to my questions!